# Error in running Logit model clustered by contry code

Tags: r, model, regression

I am just starting out in R and am trying to run a logit model with clutered country codes. My attempt is to replicate a model from [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0022343317741186) with the following [replication information](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O2Gvf7sqxYN7IsOI2zTRZANlbLnVQvvw/view) :

Data available here (data file): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O2Gvf7sqxYN7IsOI2zTRZANlbLnVQvvw/view

*Model 1: base
logit mk l.wtrivalry  mkyear mkyear2 mkyear3, cluster(ccode)

*Model 2: Controls -- no conflict
logit mk l.wtrivalry l.lnrgdppc l.polity2 l.exclid l.lnpopWB l.coupdummy mkyear mkyear2 mkyear3, cluster(ccode)

I have been trying variations of code, but keep failing to cluster correctly (unless I do so, the significance of the variables does not align with that of the paper). My attempts have been:

```
simp.logit.general. <- glm(mk ~ wtrivalry + mkyear + mkyear2 + mkyear3, data = core.data, family="binomial")
summary(simp.logit.general.)
```

robcov(simp.logit.general)

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': 'arg' should be one of “deviance”, “pearson”, “working”, “response”, “partial”

```
I have also tried: 
coeftest(simp.logit.general, vcov. = vcovCL(simp.logit.general, cluster = core.data$ccode, type = "HC0"))
```

IF anyone could help with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post, and  copy and paste the results of running `dput(core.data)`? The error suggests there’s something unusual about your dataframe, but hard to say more without seeing your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I have run the code and it returns the following:   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  (......)  , class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8595L))

Comment: I understand that is likely not helpful, so in have added a link to the dataset in the post. Thank you so much